# Joint significance test before or after hettest in Stata?

Tags: statistical-significance, least-squares, stata, misspecification

I ran an OLS regression in Stata, then a `hettest`, and there is heteroskedasticity in the X variables. So I threw on a `,robust` to the regression and ran it again. Now I want to do a joint significance test on the X variables. Should I have done that after the first regression? Or is it better to do it now, after the robust regression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This test's null hypothesis is about homoscedasticity of residuals/disturbances/errors, and not of the covariates.

Ignoring heteroskedasticity means your non-robust standard errors are typically too small, so inference will be off. However, non-spherical errors can can also be a sign of misspecification.

---

**Response to question:**

Of course it does: the variance-covariance matrix in in the middle of the [Wald test statistic forumula](http://www.stata.com/manuals14/rtest.pdf#page=21), and the robust version is the right one to use if there's hetroskedasticity.

It's easy enough to verify for yourself:

```
sysuse auto, clear
regress price weight foreign mpg
estat hettest
test weight foreign mpg
regress price weight foreign mpg, robust
test weight foreign mpg
```

As you can see, the test statistics are smaller and the p-values are larger, though the difference in the latter is infinitesimal.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. You look like you're talking about the hettest. Thank you for your insight on heteroskedasticity. But I want to know if that affects the joint significance test. Should I do the joint significance test before or after knowing there is heteroskedasticity?

Comment: @ColeTrumbo Please see above.